# getInstalledPackages returns different result in different apps

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I'm making a feature that allows users to get all Android apps from the phone.

I've made it works in an app named A. When I'm doing copy-paste code from A to app B (copy whole activity), it shows different results. Please check the screenshot below.

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<SystemApp> installedApps = new ArrayList<>();
List<PackageInfo> apps = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

This code I wrote inside an AsyncTask class. I can confirm that it is identical in both apps.

Below screenshots, I captured when debugging in the same device Android S. Please help. Thanks.

Screenshot from app A. 211 apps in total.
[image: Screenshot from app A. 211 apps in total]

Screenshot from app B. Only 69 apps in result.
[image: Screenshot from app B. Only 69 apps in result]